# Aligning a chemfig diagram and lines of text in different columns of a tblr table

Tags: tables, alignment, chemfig

I'm having trouble using the \tblr environment to make a chemistry handout. I am using TeXstudio to make a table with eight columns. The third column has a \chemfig diagram of the geometry of generic compounds (AB_5, Trigonal Bipyramidal for example). The other columns have anywhere from one to six rows of lines of text.

The problem is that the first line of text in each column aligns with the center of the picture in the third column. Thus, if there are many lines of text in a column then the result is uneven amounts of white space above and below the column text (more above) along with extra white space below the third column diagram.

My desire is to have the center of the text in every column align with the center of the third column diagram (element "A")

That is, I want minimal even white space above and below the diagram and each column's block of text regardless of how many lines of text are place into any of the columns.

Below should be an MWE of the code I am using. I also uploaded a .png graphic adjusted in Paint showing what I am aiming for:  Center alignment along the thick black line with the red X'ed out white space removed.

```
\documentclass[10pt,leqno]{article}
%%% BEGIN PACKAGES
\usepackage{libertine} % Makes spacing nicely smaller.
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath} % Adjusts font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Adjusts font
\usepackage{chemfig} % For building molecular diagrams.
\usepackage{tabularray} % Provides tblr environment.
\usepackage[strict]{chngpage} % Provides adjustwidth page environment for tables.
%%% END PACKAGES

%%% BEGIN CUSTOM
\newcommand{\textbfun}[1]{\underline{\textbf{#1}}} % Bold + Underline text simultaneously.
%%% END CUSTOM

%%% BEGIN FORMATTING
\oddsidemargin      0.0cm
\evensidemargin     0.0cm
\textwidth          16.5cm
\headheight         0.0cm
\topmargin          0.0cm
\textheight         20.0cm
%%% END FORMATTING

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-60pt}{0pt}
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=5pt}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines,
            vlines,
            colspec={ccccccl}
        }
        
        {$e^-$ Density 
            \\ Regions} 
        & {Generic 
            \\ Formula} 
        & {Molecular 
            \\ Structure} 
        & Hybridization 
        & {Electronic 
            \\ Geometry} 
        & {Molecular 
            \\ Geometry} 
        & {Ideal Bond 
            \\ Angle} 
        & {Molecular Polarity}\\
    
        5 
        & AB$_5$ 
        & \chemfig{A(<:[:30]B)(-[2]B)(-[4]B)(-[6]B)(<[:330]B)}
        & sp$^3$d 
        & {Trigonal 
            \\ Bipyramidal} 
        & {Trigonal 
            \\ Bipyramidal} 
        & {$180^\circ$ Axial 
            \\ $120^\circ$ Equitorial 
            \\ \phantom{x} 
            \\ $ 90^\circ$ Axial to 
            \\ Equitorial} 
        & {"B" atoms are all the same 
            \\ Yes $\rightarrow$ Non-Polar 
            \\ No $\rightarrow$ Same two axial "B" \textbfun{and} 
            \\ \phantom{Yes $\rightarrow$} same three equitorial "B" 
            \\ \phantom{Yes $\rightarrow$} \qquad Yes $\rightarrow$ Non-Polar 
            \\ \phantom{Yes $\rightarrow$} \qquad No $\rightarrow$ Polar}\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{adjustwidth}\vspace{0.5cm}

\textbf{Desired: .png adjusted with Microsoft Paint (Align to thick black line. Remove red X'ed white space.}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-60pt}{0pt}
\includegraphics[scale=.78]{Line&X}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image: Have vs. Want]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think, you want something like `colspec={*{6}{Q[c,m]}*{2}{Q[l,m]}}`. (`*{6}{...}` means: "6 times the column defined in the second argument"; `Q[c,m]` means: "horizontally centered, vertically centered"; `Q[l,m]` means: "left-aligned, vertically centered".)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the column definitions from `c` to `Q[c,m]` and from `l` to `Q[l,m]` which not only horizontally aligns the text, but also centers the contents of the cell vertically. Also, I would suggest that you make use of the `*` notation to avoid repetitions in the `colspec` option:

```
\documentclass[10pt,leqno]{article}
%%% BEGIN PACKAGES
\usepackage{libertine} % Makes spacing nicely smaller.
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath} % Adjusts font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Adjusts font
\usepackage{chemfig} % For building molecular diagrams.
\usepackage{tabularray} % Provides tblr environment.
\usepackage[strict]{chngpage} % Provides adjustwidth page environment for tables.
%%% END PACKAGES

%%% BEGIN CUSTOM
\newcommand{\textbfun}[1]{\underline{\textbf{#1}}} % Bold + Underline text simultaneously.
%%% END CUSTOM

%%% BEGIN FORMATTING
\oddsidemargin      0.0cm
\evensidemargin     0.0cm
\textwidth          16.5cm
\headheight         0.0cm
\topmargin          0.0cm
\textheight         20.0cm
%%% END FORMATTING

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-60pt}{0pt}
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=5pt}
    \begin{tblr}{
        hlines,
        vlines,
        colspec={ *{7}{Q[c,m]} Q[l,m] }
    }
        
        {$e^-$ Density 
            \\ Regions} 
        & {Generic 
            \\ Formula} 
        & {Molecular 
            \\ Structure} 
        & Hybridization 
        & {Electronic 
            \\ Geometry} 
        & {Molecular 
            \\ Geometry} 
        & {Ideal Bond 
            \\ Angle} 
        & {Molecular Polarity}\\
    
        5 
        & AB$_5$ 
        & \chemfig{A(<:[:30]B)(-[2]B)(-[4]B)(-[6]B)(<[:330]B)}
        & sp$^3$d 
        & {Trigonal 
            \\ Bipyramidal} 
        & {Trigonal 
            \\ Bipyramidal} 
        & {$180^\circ$ Axial 
            \\ $120^\circ$ Equitorial 
            \\ \phantom{x} 
            \\ $ 90^\circ$ Axial to 
            \\ Equitorial} 
        & {``B'' atoms are all the same 
            \\ Yes $\rightarrow$ Non-Polar 
            \\ No $\rightarrow$ Same two axial ``B'' \textbfun{and} 
            \\ \phantom{Yes $\rightarrow$} same three equitorial ``B'' 
            \\ \phantom{Yes $\rightarrow$} \qquad Yes $\rightarrow$ Non-Polar 
            \\ \phantom{Yes $\rightarrow$} \qquad No $\rightarrow$ Polar}\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

(Side notes: I think, your original `colspec` definition is missing one column, which is not really a problem, because `l` is used per default. I changed `"` to the typographically correct ``` `` ``` and `''` in the above example.)

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was so focused on trying to make a reference column for the other columns that I missed simply setting each column to center-middle independently. Thank you so much!